# sprites move in different speed

Tags: python, pygame, sprite

I encounter a problem in my 2D game but I don't know why.
I want to move sprites when the player reaches the middle of the game screen, but the sprites start to move in a slower speed, when they are 1px out of screen (That doesn't make sense to me...)

This is the only part in my code, in which i defined such a movement of the sprites:

```
        if self.player.rect.centerx >= WIDTH/2:
            # Ensuring the player stays in the middle of the screen
            self.player.pos.x -= abs(self.player.vel.x)
            for obj in self.movables:
                # Relocating Sprite when Player moves
                obj.rect.x -= abs(self.player.vel.x)
                # Killin Sprite when it is out of the screen
                if obj.rect.x < 0 - obj.rect.width:
                    obj.kill()
                # Reseting Location of the Ground
                if self.ground.rect.centerx <= 0:
                    self.ground.rect.x = 0
```

EDIT: cleaned up the code

Here is the part where the velocity of the player is being calculated:

```
        def event(self):
            keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
            if keys[pygame.K_LEFT] or keys[pygame.K_a]:
                self.acc.x = -PLAYER_ACC
            if keys[pygame.K_RIGHT] or keys[pygame.K_d]:
                self.acc.x = PLAYER_ACC


        def update(self):
            self.acc = vec(0, PLAYER_GRAV)
            self.event()
            self.acc.x += self.vel.x * PLAYER_FRICTION
            self.vel += self.acc
            # Die Vel auf null setzen wenn sie ~0 ist
            if abs(self.vel.x) < 0.1:
                self.vel.x = 0
            # Physik
            self.pos += self.vel + 0.5 * self.acc
            self.rect.midbottom = self.pos
```

Comment: it seems to be tied to the `player.vel` i think we need that part too

Comment: I've edited to my post

Comment: The odd movement where the sprites are moving slower when a part of themselves is out of the screen happens only when I let go K_d.

Comment: Please provide a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that we can just copy, paste and run, otherwise it's very difficult to reproduce the problem and to find its cause.

Comment: It took some time, because I was at a seminar, but right now I've added a code example. It is in the answer

Answer (score 0):

I've added a code example of my problem. But in this code the player disappears after a few seconds, I think it has to do in the way I handle the collision with the platforms, but for now I don't know how to fix this too :D

To clearly see the problem of the moving sprites: Keep pressing "d", when the plat is half way out of the screen don't press the key "d" and you can see how the sprite is moving slower compared to the rest of the sprites on the screen

```
            import pygame
            WIDTH = 800
            HEIGHT = 600
            BGCOLOR = (181, 45, 76)
            BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
            # Player Properties
            PLAYER_ACC = 0.5
            PLAYER_FRICTION = -0.12
            PLAYER_GRAV = 0.5
            PLAYER_JUMP = -20


            class Platform(pygame.sprite.Sprite):

                def __init__(self, game, x, y, w, h):
                    self._layer = 1
                    self.groups = game.all_sprites, game.movables, game.platforms
                    pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self, self.groups)
                    self.game = game
                    self.image = pygame.Surface((w, h))
                    self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
                    self.rect.x = x
                    self.rect.y = y

            class Ground(pygame.sprite.Sprite):

                def __init__(self, game, x, y, w, h):
                    self._layer = 1
                    self.groups = game.all_sprites, game.movables, game.platforms
                    pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self, self.groups)
                    self.game = game
                    self.image = pygame.Surface((w, h))
                    self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
                    self.rect.x = x
                    self.rect.y = y

            vec = pygame.math.Vector2

            class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):

                def __init__(self, game):
                self._layer = 2
                self.groups = game.all_sprites
                pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self, self.groups)
                self.game = game
                self.image = pygame.Surface((30, 40))
                self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
                self.rect.center = (WIDTH/2, HEIGHT/2)
                self.pos = (WIDTH/2, HEIGHT/2)

                self.vel = vec(0, 0)
                self.acc = vec(0, 0)
                self.jumping = False

                def event(self):
                keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
                if keys[pygame.K_LEFT] or keys[pygame.K_a]:
                    self.acc.x = -PLAYER_ACC
                if keys[pygame.K_RIGHT] or keys[pygame.K_d]:
                    self.acc.x = PLAYER_ACC


                def update(self):
                self.acc = vec(0, PLAYER_GRAV)
                self.event()
                self.acc.x += self.vel.x * PLAYER_FRICTION
                self.vel += self.acc
                # Die Vel auf null setzen wenn sie ~0 ist
                if abs(self.vel.x) < 0.1:
                    self.vel.x = 0
                # Physik
                self.pos += self.vel + 0.5 * self.acc
                self.rect.midbottom = self.pos

                def jump(self):
                # Checking if the Player can Jump
                self.rect.y += 1
                hits = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(self.game.player, self.game.platforms, False)
                self.rect.y -= 1
                if hits:
                    if not self.jumping:
                    self.jumping = True
                    # Dieser Teil des Codes wird nie erreicht!!!
                    self.vel.y = PLAYER_JUMP

            class Game:
                def __init__(self):
                self.running = True
                pygame.init()
                self.clock = pygame.time.Clock()
                self.screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800, 600))
                pygame.display.set_caption("Moving Bug")

                def new(self):
                self.all_sprites = pygame.sprite.LayeredUpdates()
                self.movables = pygame.sprite.Group()
                self.platforms = pygame.sprite.Group()
                self.ground = Ground(self, 0, HEIGHT-20, WIDTH*2, 20)
                self.plat_1 = Platform(self, 400, 300, 100, 20)
                self.plat_2 = Platform(self, 800, 400, 100, 20)
                self.plat_3 = Platform(self, 100, 40, 100, 20)
                self.player = Player(self)
                self.run()

                def run(self):
                self.playing = True
                while self.playing:
                    self.clock.tick(60)
                    self.event()
                    self.update()
                    self.draw()

                def event(self):
                for event in pygame.event.get():
                    if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                    if self.playing:
                        self.playing = False
                    self.running = False
                    if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                    if event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
                        self.player.jump()

                def update(self):
                self.all_sprites.update()
                # Only checking for collision if the player is jumping
                if self.player.vel.y > 0:
                    hits = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(self.player, self.platforms, False)
                    if hits:
                    self.player.vel.y = 0
                    self.player.rect.bottom = hits[0].rect.top
                    self.player.jumping = False
                # Left side of the screen
                if self.player.rect.x < 0:
                    self.player.vel.x = 0
                    self.player.rect.x = 0
                # Centering the player in the middle:
                if self.player.rect.centerx >= WIDTH/2:
                    # Ensuring the player stays in the middle of the screen
                    self.player.pos.x -= abs(self.player.vel.x)
                    for obj in self.movables:
                    # Relocating Sprite when Player moves
                    obj.rect.x -= abs(self.player.vel.x)
                    # Killin Sprite when it is out of the screen
                    if obj.rect.x < 0 - obj.rect.width:
                        obj.rect.x = WIDTH
                    # Reseting Location of the Ground
                    if self.ground.rect.centerx <= 0:
                        self.ground.rect.x = 0

                def draw(self):
                self.screen.fill(BGCOLOR)
                self.all_sprites.draw(self.screen)
                pygame.display.flip()

            g = Game()
            while g.running:
                g.new()
                g.run()
            pygame.quit()
```